# RPA not clicking the 'Like' button in Child window even when anchor identified

Tags: rpa, uipath

[image]I have attached the activity I did with RPA to automate clicking of Facebook 'like' button in child window. Even when the RPA activity click has successfully identified the element and anchor element, UiPath is not clicking the 'Like' button but it passed.

Here is the [video representation](https://youtu.be/jTda7rzPxlM) of what I am saying.

[image: which activity to choose to maximize browser]

[image: Chrome Dev tools Selector of <code>Like</code> button in Child window]

Comment: You don't need an anchor here. I think you do not have a proper selector. It's hard to tell you the correct selector as I cannot test it.

Comment: Is there a way to maximise the child browser using RPA? tried with click activity of RPA but RPA not recognising the maximise button of child browser

Comment: Here the best would be to use the activity called "Maximize window". If not working you need to set the "Window" property. The window is just the browser object. So somewhere you have the "Start browser" and there is another property called "Output > Browser". But I don't think it's an issue of maximizing windows in your case. You should go the way with a proper selector.

Comment: trying to send a hotkey with the selector set to that browser element,problem is click didnt worked,which one should i try?

Comment: Please show me images of the Browser DOM of the like button. And show the selector that you try to use.

Comment: Here is ```Like``` DOM model in child window

Comment: also selector i used is "Image verification"

Comment: Don't use Image verification. You have a proper selector. Switch back to usual DOM selector. Can you try use the Ui Explorer? Select the like button and show me your selector you got.

Comment: Also what is your error message. Can you add that to the post and not as image.

Comment: i am using studio X ,i think i should change the studio which you use,let me know which one you use?

Comment: Hope my solution works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter which version you use. But you better switch back to the **Community version 20**. In that version your process look a bit like mine. I created on account on your **like4like** page and tested your case.

Process:
[image: UiPath Process]

That process clicks any Like button on the focused tab. For me that worked on several tests.

The Click Like Button selector is:

```
"<html app='firefox.exe' idx='25' /><webctrl aaname='Like' tag='A' colName='Like' innertext='Like' rowName='Like' />"
```

You do not have to use the `Attach Browser`. But I would recommend that if you use more than one Click activity.

You can find Studio and StudioX on the same page. It's a bit confusing as StudioX is currently just available on the non-stable release:

[image: stuido/studiox]

Comment: How to download UIPath studio community and not Studio Xcurrently in https://cloud.uipath.com/tuhaajxmfsmc/portal_/home is only see option of downloading UI path Community version 20 . ,In dont see options like Sequence,Attach browser,

Comment: Just added an image that makes clear is what. Hope that helps. And better always use Stable releases instead of preview.

Comment: You're welcome. Come back here if you have additional questions.

Comment: please can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011341/how-to-close-the-child-tab-using-close-tab-activity-in-uipath