# How to close the child tab using Close tab activity in UIPath

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

UiPath is **closing** the **main window** instead of child window. I have defined a browser variable in the `attach browser` activity and passed that browser variable to the `Close tab` activity. The main Chrome window is still getting closed.

[image: Input browser variable from attach browser output]

[image: Output variable browser2 from attach browser]

Also attached is the project xaml file https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ykpHvFEc7DkCI7enUAOgExWBN6KHKQo-?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot open your project. But that solution via hotkey should be a proper solution I would also recommend you.

Comment: @kwoxer - why can't she click the close button on the child window. I agree sending the hot key may help but clicking the close buton should work. Atleast that's what has been suggested int he RFE frameworks assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, It would be alot more easier, if you use [send hotkey activity](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/send-hotkey) of UI path with "CTRL + w" to close the active tab.

[image]